# How to display Facebook friends profile images?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have requirement to get Facebook friends list with their images. How can I store every friend data in bean?

Comment: you should go on [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please refer the Graph API for profile pictures

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/